# Merge CSV files by rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
tvshows.csv = tvID | tvName

ratings.csv = userID | tvID | userRating
```

I have the following 2 CSV files with these columns. I wish to merge the columns so that the tvName column from tvshows.csv is displayed in ratings.csv corresponding to the correct tvID.

The main issue I am facing is that there are several of the same tvID data in the ratings.csv file as there are many users who may rate the same tv shows. (e.g, 5 people will rate The Simpsons, creating 5 The Simpsons tvIDs). Is there a way for me to take the tvName from tvshows.csv and merge it with the correct tvID in ratings.csv, bearing in mind there may be several of the same tvID in ratings.csv.

I am hoping to complete the task in Python using Pandas, appreciate any help provided.

Example of the data for tvshows.csv:

```
tvID | tvName
862  |  The Simpsons
8844 |  Futurama
15602| Paw Patrol
```

Example of the data for ratings.csv:

```
userID | tvID  | rating
1      |  862  |  7
2      |  8844 |  6
3      |  862  |  8
```

Comment: please show some sample data along with your headings.

Comment: Please don't add image of the test data as it can't be copy-pasted. I have added an answer from a toy data.

Comment: I have attached some sample data

Comment: if I understand you, you need to a join on the tyID key on the rating table, if that's the case please see the duplicate question as it goes over `merge` in detail.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, it did assist me.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYWKfUOtGaw I also found this youtube video which is very similar to the task I am working on. Starts at around 7:40min

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can read `CSV` files, you can use [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method from pandas:

```
ratings.merge(tvshows, on = 'tvID')
```

Here is a random toy example:

```
import pandas as pd

#generating test data
tvshows = pd.DataFrame({'tvName':['Ab','Bc','Cd','De','Ef'],'tvID':['A','B','C','D','E']})
ratings = pd.DataFrame({'userID':[1,2,3,4,5],'userRating':[5,5,3,5,5],'tvID':['A','B','C','D','E']})

#merging the dataframes
out = ratings.merge(tvshows, on = 'tvID')
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   userID  userRating tvID tvName
0       1           5    A     Ab
1       2           5    B     Bc
2       3           3    C     Cd
3       4           5    D     De
4       5           5    E     Ef
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use merge:

```
tvshows = pd.read_csv('tvshows.csv')
ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')
tvshows_ratings = tvshows.merge(ratings)
```